# vkontakte api не работает при закрытом аккаунте

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Зарегистрировал приложение для использования vk api, но данные почему-то не загружаются, если я выхожу из своего аккаунта vk! Значит ли это, что надо все время держать аккаунт открытым, чтобы приложение работало?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Токен, с которым работает приложение, должен иметь разрешение на работу Offline. При запросе [разрешений](https://vk.com/dev/permissions), просите ещё и "offline" (65536).

Answer (score 0):

Нет, приложение работает само по себе.